# Puppeteer - How to evaluate XPath which returns text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I am trying to get the text from the following Xpath as a string:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'mission')]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

I have tried

```
let elHandle = await page.$x("//*[contains(text(), 'mission')]/following-sibling::text()[1]")
```

which returns an `ElementHandle<Element>[]`. How can I navigate from here to get to the text string?

Comment: Also, is there a CSS selector that does the same thing, or something similar, to this XPath one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your XPath is correct. So: [`page.$x`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagexexpression) returns an array (of matched elements: `<Promise<Array<ElementHandle>>>`) where you need the 1st element so you will need to add `[0]` after the whole element handle expression.

It can be combined with a [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to retrieve the `innerText` string.

```js
const elHandleText = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, (await page.$x("//*[contains(text(), 'mission')]/following-sibling::text()[1]"))[0])
console.log(elHandleText)
```

---

Your question about if it can be done with CSS selectors: It is not possible, XPath's [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) method is the solution if you need to find an element with specific text content.

Comment: Thanks!. I'll be looking into page.evaluate